# Zend Route, change action with no change params

Tags: php, zend-framework, action, parameters

1: I need to change this link (action index)

local:8080/default/acc/**index**/PageDate/2011-05-01/ServerId/1/

to other (action catch)

local:8080/default/acc/**catch**/PageDate/2011-05-01/ServerId/1/

2: I need to set default params, to various variables. For example I wont to use this links

local:8080/default/acc/catch/PageDate/2011-05-01/ServerId/1/

or

local:8080/default/acc/catch/PageDate/2011-05-01/

or

local:8080/default/acc/catch/ServerId/1/

like this

```
$route =  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            'default/accountant/index ???',
            array(
                  'module' => 'default',
                  'controller' => 'acc',
                  'action' => 'catch',
                  'ServerId' => 0,
                  'PageDate' => '2011-01-01', // and  many others
            )
            ,array(

            )
            ,'default/acc/index/'
        );
```

But I dont know how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the regex route or any special route at all. What you probably need to do is use the link view helper or action helper

Answer (score 0):

To forward index action to catch action, use `_forward` method inside index action.

For matching multiple URLs mentioned in point 2, do not use any routers at all. Zend routes those automatically to appropriate controllers and actions with the parameter values too.